# Generating a pdf-file out of a twig template

Tags: html, css, symfony, pdf-generation, twig

I want to generate a pdf (an invoice as letter) out of a twig template. The template uses a css and contains a header with a logo (png-image) and a footer, which should appear at the bottom of the document.

I tried it with the KnpSnappyBundle, but this doesn't work (css only works inline, images are not rendered..., etc.). Are there any other tools to generate a pdf?

With Java I used jasper-reports (really cool), isn't there anything similar for php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: The server startet via

```
php app/console server:run
```

is single-threaded, so there is no chance, to get a response, when requesting an image or css-file...

Answer (score 2):

I have used KnpSnappyBundle to generate pdf before, and it worked with external css files, thought there's is some diffrence bettween regular tempaltes:

When linking asset you have to provide absolute path:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/css.css', null, true) }}" />
```

I didn't needed images files, but I think it should work the same, also you need to use "renderView" method instead of "render".

```
$pdf = $this->renderView('**:**:tempalte.html.twig', array());
```

After that you just simple use:

```
$file = $this->container->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml(pdf);
```

Comment: I don't think timeouts are caused by the knp bundle, eitheir way, I can't say much without seeing the code.